# How to cache httpClient response on routerLink?

Tags: angular

In my Angular App i have a page where i load all products from my API, from the same page on each product click i'm doing a routerLink redirect to item details page. When the user get's back to products page all of them are reloaded again from my API and i would prevent it by cachin em.

How could i archieve it?

I've tryed by using shareReplay but it's not working at all..
Here is the code i've tryed:

In my component constructor:

```
//SERVICE:

      plu(idNegozio: string, piva: string, lang?: string): Observable<Plu[]>{
        return this.http
        .get(`${Globals.API_URL}/plu/${piva}/${idNegozio}`, {params: { lang }})
        .pipe(map((data: any[]) => data.map(item => this.adapter.adapt(item))), shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true }));
      }

//COMPONENT:
        
      constructor(
        pluService: PluService
      ) { }


      getPlu(): void {
        this.pluService
          .plu(this.idNegozio.toString(), this.piva, 'IT')
          .subscribe((data) => {
            this.plus = data;
            this.menu = this.menu.filter((menu) =>
              this.plus.some((item) => item.menu === menu.id)
            );
            this.filterPlu(this.menu[0].id);
          });
      }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getPlu(); // getting data on init
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the variable dataPlu: Observable<Plu[]>; to your service and only call your api if there is no data in it. And make sure you unsubscribe from the observable in your ngOnDestroy method of your component.

Answer (score 0):

Since I guess you're not using any store like NgRx you can use some subject within the service and subscribe to it instead of the method itself.

Service

```
private isLoaded$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> =  new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
private _dataSubject: Subject<YourType> = new Subject<YourType>();
dataSubject$: Observable<YourType> = this._dataSubject.asObservable();

plu(param1, param2, param3): Observable<boolean> {
  // I assume you are using some HTTP Get
  this._dataSubject = this.httpClient.get(...).pipe(
    finalize(() => this.isLoaded.next(true)
  );
)}
```

Component

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.pluService$.isLoaded.pipe(
    filter(isLoaded => !isLoaded)
  ).subscribe(res => {
    // Only load when no data were loaded before.
    this.pluService.plu();
  });

  this.pluService.dataSubject$.subscribe(res => {
    this.data = res;
    ...
  })
}
```

This way you can also implement some refresh data method, which would bypass the onInit check and can update your data on demand.